# How to Display Prices in Dropdown for Configurable Product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, configurable-product-options

I want to display the prices in dropdown for configurable product ,
Like this :

https://prnt.sc/XEfmjtI4Dni4

can anyone guide me step by step how can I do so ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Jantar Mantar, Magento already displaying the option prices to the configurable product dropdown. No customizations required here.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create the configurable product and add/assign simple products by setting up the product configuration.

After creating the product, the price will be automatically displayed in the same manner as shown in the screenshot you shared.